# WindowsやLinuxにおいて、CPU CacheをWritebackしたり、Invalidateしたりする関数はあるのでしょうか？

Tags: linux, windows, cpu

WindowsやLinuxにおいて、ドライバ開発をする際にはCPU Cache操作が必要になることがあるとおもいますが、CPU CacheをWritebackしたり、Invalidateしたりする関数はあるのでしょうか？

x86の命令には、WBINVD命令（Write Back and Invalidate Cache）やINVD命令（Invalidate Internal Caches）があると思うので最終的にはこの命令を呼ぶとおもうのですが、これらをラップした関数が用意されているのか教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 確認ですがCPUキャッシュの制御に関する質問でしょうか？

Comment: はい。CPUキャッシュの制御をするAPIがあるのであれば、教えていただきたいです。

Comment: マルチポスト　http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1485510092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C++ですと[`<intrin.h>`ヘッダーに定義されている`__wbinvd`関数](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ct1z0fcz.aspx)を使うことで`WBINVD`命令に展開できます。

Comment: windowsの情報もありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

メモリマップドI/Oとかでしょうか。

たとえばLinuxに含まれるfbdev（フレームバッファドライバ）の場合、wbinvdをインラインアセンブラで呼び出すインライン関数を定義しています。

```
static inline void flush_cache(void)
{
        asm volatile ("wbinvd":::"memory");
}
```

まあ、ラップしなくちゃならないほどのものでもないかと。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
はい、メモリマップドIOだとおもいます。
大変勉強になりました。